Filter inside Create view in ASP.NET MVC
Need some advice on the correct approach for the next scenario.
I have three model classes:
namespace App.Models
{
    public partial class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
    }

    public partial class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; };
    }

    public partial class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Department { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; };
    }
}

When I access the Create view of the UserController, I have a combobox to select the DepartmentID.
The problem is that the list is too big. I would like to add within the view, a list to select the Company. And in the Department combobox, only the Departments within the selected Company should appear.
Any advice on the correct way to achieve this? I already know how to filter the Departments by Company within the view bag.
But I don't know how to make the change within the view and send the filter to the controller.
Thanks in advance.

In order to filter departments based on company selection in an ASP.NET MVC Create view, leverage AJAX. Add company and department dropdown lists. Use Javascript to trigger an AJAX request on company change, sending the ID to a new controller action. This action filters departments by company ID, returning JSON data that populates the department dropdown list in the view's Javascript success callback. By the way which version of .NET you are using?

@MdFaridUddinKiron I'am using .NET 7.0. I'm going to try to do this. It hadn't occurred to me until now, since I understood that all the logic had to be written in the controllers, and not in the views. I'll see if I can do it that way.


Any advice on the correct way to achieve this? I already know how to
filter the Departments by Company within the view bag.
But I don't know how to make the change within the view and send the
filter to the controller

Well, first of all load your compay within your view. All you need to do is, query your company object and bind it into ViewBag. You can do as following:
ViewBag.Companies = _context.Companies.ToList();

Within the view, you should have following code:
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CompanyId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="CompanyId" class="form-control" onchange="getDepartments(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Company</option>
            @foreach (var company in ViewBag.Companies)
            {
                <option value="@company.ID">@company.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

Now, in order to load department based on selected company, you should get the company Id and then call a API for getting the department based on the company Id passed. Use ajax request to implement that.
You can do as following:
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="DepartmentId" id="departmentDropdown" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Department</option>
        </select>
    </div>

Script:
<script>
    function getDepartments(companyId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/User/GetDepartments',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { companyId: companyId },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#departmentDropdown').empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, department) {
                    $('#departmentDropdown').append($('<option>').text(department.name).attr('value', department.id));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>

Controller:
public IActionResult GetDepartments(int companyId)
{
    var departments = _context.Departments.Where(d => d.CompanyID == companyId).ToList();
    return Json(departments);
}

Note: Make sure your ajax request URL point to your controller accordingly.

This worked wonders for me. What was blocking me was the AJAX Request part, I didn't fully understand the flow of the data. With your example I was already able to implement it in the rest of my Project. Thanks a lot man.

Gald to assist you on this.
